# Flask SQLAlchemy custom field name for foreign key?

Tags: flask, model, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Relationship = Many `Hero`s have one `Planet`.

I'd like to be able to call `hero.home_planet` because the Star Wars characters move around in space a lot. But under my model, the field is called `planet_id`.

Is there a way to set a custom name for a foreign key field?

Like a `planet_id = db.Column( name ='home_planet')`?

Could I just change the name of the table name to `__tablename__ = 'home_planet'`?

```
class Hero(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'heroes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    race = db.Column(db.String())
    planet_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('planets.id'), nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Hero %r>' % self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `flask_sqlalchemy`:

```
class Planet(db.Model)
    __tablename__ = 'planet'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    heros = db.relationship('Hero', backref='home_planet')

class Hero(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'heroes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    race = db.Column(db.String())
    planet_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('planets.id'), nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Hero %r>' % self.name
```

Now you can call `your_hero.home_planet`

Answer (score 0):

It's worth going through the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one) to learn about the huge number of options you can use here, but it sounds like a simple `relationship()` will work:

```
planet = relationship('Planet', backref='heroes')
```

You can now call `my_hero.planet`, or the reverse `my_planet.heroes`